# Showing AlertDialog in onCancelled throws and Exception

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm developing an Android app and I am using AsyncTask to connect to the server, send and retrieve some values etc.

Before I even connect to the server, I check whether the phone is connected to the internet and some validation checks in `doInBackground()` as well. If any of these checks fail, I cancel the task and set a cancellation message string, which will be later used to give a proper message to the user.

Now, the problem occurs when I want to display an AlertDialog inside onCancelled method. I tried showing a Toast, just to make sure I can reach the activity, it worked.

After hours of searching the web and trying to solve the problem myself, I did not find a solution.

**Note:** I'm passing the current application context inside the constructor of the class that I'm extending.

```
@Override
protected void onCancelled(){

String cancellationMessage = "";

// Some stuff goes in here to set the proper value for cancellationMessage.

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(currentActivityContext);
builder.setTitle("Oops, something went wrong!")
        .setMessage(cancellationMessage)
        .setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }).create().show();

}
```

It looks like calling `builder.show();` throws that exception.

Why this problem occurs when onCancelled runs on UI Thread? Any idea? 
By the way, I am getting this Exception in the logcat tab when I try to show an alert dialog:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

Comment: How do you have declared and initialized your `AsyncTask`?

Comment: Is `currentActivityContext` really an Activity context? Usually this message occurs if you try showing the dialog using the application context such as that returned by the `getApplicationContext()` method on an Activity. You need to use an `Activity` context in order to show the dialog.

Comment: who's abstract method is onCancelled()? i mean which class are you overriding its onCancelled()?

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan, yes, this is an Activity's context. As I said, I pass an Activity context in the constructor. And that context is held by the `currentActivityContext` variable :)

Comment: @WildChild your answer is exactly what i mentioned in the comment. What you were using before was not an activity context.

Comment: @George Mulligan Yeah, sorry. It was a misunderstanding. I'm beginner in Android and everything is new to me. I checked the differences and everything is clear to me now and makes more sense. Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, folks, I found the solution.
Instead of `getApplicationContext()`, I passed `this` in the constructor of the class as an activity context. It works like a charm now, hey!
The old code:

```
public void signMeIn(View v){
    String email = (String) ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.signInEmailText)).getText().toString();
    String password = (String) ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.signInPasswordText)).getText().toString();

    UserCredentialsAsync uca = new UserCredentialsAsync(getApplicationContext());
    uca.signIn(email, password);
    uca.execute();
}
```

And the new code:

```
public void signMeIn(View v){
    String email = (String) ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.signInEmailText)).getText().toString();
    String password = (String) ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.signInPasswordText)).getText().toString();

    UserCredentialsAsync uca = new UserCredentialsAsync(this);
    uca.signIn(email, password);
    uca.execute();
}
```